# SQL Server 2008 R2 - delete references

Tags: diagram, relationships

I have got the following problem: I created a database diagram in a database which is used by a special software. This software creates its own relationships programmatically - I only created the diagram to show the relationships to someone who is not familiar with the software.

I told the admin to delete the diagram, which he did, nonetheless there seem to be relationships from this diagram interfering with the software.

Do you have any idea how I can get rid of all the relationships?

Answer (score 0):

Start `SQL Server Management Studio` (awesome tool). Use the tree view on the left, navigate to your database and subsequent to your tables. Check out, review and delete the relations if necessary.